# Handling submit and preventing submit on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modifyActionURL; 
    $(document).ready( function() { 
            modifyActionURL = function(obj) {  
                if (($('.checkboxclass:checked').length == 1)) {  
                    $("#searchForm").attr("action", obj); 
                } else if ($('.checkboxclass:checked').length > 1) { 
                    $("#dialogOnlyOne").dialog({
                        height: 200,
                        width: 500,                                                 
                        modal: true,
                        open: function (type, data) {
                            $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 9999);                                         
                            $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); 
                        },
                        close: function(event, ui) {
                            $("#dialogOnlyOne").hide(); 
                        },
                         buttons: [
                                    {
                                          text: "Ok",
                                          type: "button",
                                          click: function() {
                                              $(this).dialog("close");
                                          }                                           
                                      }  
                                ]
                        }); 
                } else {
                    alert('Please select a row');
                }
            };
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="#" th:object="${search}" method="post">           
    <div id="dialogOnlyOne" class="window">
        <p style="background-color: #ffffff">Please select only one row.</p>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Modify" class="btn btn-primary" id="modify" th:onclick="'javascript:modifyActionURL(\'' + @{/search/modify} +  '\')'" />
</form>
```

When the checked length     is 1, the page should be submitted. When the length is greater than one, dialog box should be displayed and on click of `ok`, the dialog box should close without submitting or refreshing the page. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Your OK button isn't submitting the form, what is the problem that you are facing.? In your dialog however I see a <input type = "submit" /> you can change that to <input type="button" />

Comment: @progrAmmar The question says that clicking OK should close the dialogue _without_ submitting the form.

Comment: @progrAmmar `<input type="button" />` will work but that will fail for `if` condition. In that condition it will not submit.

Comment: @progrAmmar. The expectation is , it should submit for `if` condition, and it should not submit for `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `false` from the function to prevent the form from submitting.

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    modifyActionURL = function(obj) {  
        if (($('.checkboxclass:checked').length == 1)) {  
            $("#searchForm").attr("action", obj); 
        } else if ($('.checkboxclass:checked').length > 1) { 
            $("#dialogOnlyOne").dialog({
                height: 200,
                width: 500,                                                 
                modal: true,
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index', 9999);                                         
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); 
                },
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#dialogOnlyOne").hide(); 
                },
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Ok",
                        type: "button",
                        click: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }                                           
                    }  
                ]
            });
            return false; // prevent form submission
        } else {
            alert('Please select a row');
            return false; // prevent form submission
        }
    };
});
```

You also need to return the value of the function in the `onclick`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Modify" class="btn btn-primary" id="modify" th:onclick="'return modifyActionURL(\'' + @{/search/modify} +  '\')'" />
```

BTW, you don't need `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed when you put Javascript in an attribute that normally contains a URL, like `href`.

Comment: I have tried `return false;` and `e.preventDefault`. Both are not working

Comment: You also need to have a `return` statement in the `onclick`, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use a onsubmit event attached to your form, instead of the onclick event directly on the submit button.

There is clear exemple of using the onsubmit event with jQuery here
https://api.jquery.com/submit/

To prevent the form from submitting you will have something close to

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your function is missing the `obj` parameter, which is used to replace the `action` attribute of the form.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was trying to show the best way to block a submit event by using the event.preventDefault(); method

Comment: I understand that. But if the fix causes another problem, it's not very helpful.